# Jquery issue with on()

Tags: jquery

I have created a fiddle to add two values and output the value. Fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/2215/

When I enter values for input box(G7), value adds to G8 and shows the output. But when I delete the value in the input box using backspace, the value in the G8 doesn't change to the default value(0). I have tried with `.on()` and `.bind()`. But no luck. Please help me to find out the issue.

I am using the following event:

```
 $("#g7").on("input keyup keydown keypress change blur", function() {});
```

Thanks.

Comment: add code to OP not just an external link..for demo use `<>`

Comment: The problem isn't with `.on()`, it's with the code inside your event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `#g7` is empty, parseFloat returns an empty string, so doing an addition operation on that results in `NaN`.  Also, you don't need all those events, in fact having all those events means that your funciton fires multiple times per keypress.  The `keyup` event should be sufficient, unless that input field is being externally updated, in which case you might use the `change` event as well.  Still, if you're doing external updates, I would preference forcing the update by doing something like `$('#g7').trigger('keyup');` to trigger the event manually.

Try this code for your jQuery, it appears to work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#g7").on("keyup", function() {
        var g6 =$('#g6').text();
        var g7 =$('#g7').val() || 0;
        var g8 =$('#g8').text();

        var noCommasg6 = $('#g6').text().replace(/,/g, ''),
        asANumber = +noCommasg6;

        var sum=parseFloat(noCommasg6)+parseFloat(g7);
        if (!isNaN(sum))
        {
            $("#g8").text(sum);
            $('#g8').number( true, 2 );
        }
    });
});
```

Some other things to note:

- `$('#g8').number( true, 2 );` errors out with the message `$(...).number is not a function`
- You might want to restrict the values that can go in `#g7` by changing the HTML `input type="..."` to `number` (instead of `text`), so that alphabetic characters don't creep in

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: No worries.  I don't think I noted what I did, which is used a null coalescing operator on line 4, meaning that if `$('#g7').val()` is empty/null/0/etc, then it defaults the value to 0.  This is a quick and simple way of creating a default, there are more robust ways, but this should suffice for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete all the characters in the input field, the value becomes an empty string.

`var sum=parseFloat(noCommasg6)+parseFloat(g7);`

Parse float on this line will evaluate to NaN

```
if (!isNaN(sum))
               {
                    $("#g8").text(sum);
                    $('#g8').number( true, 2 );
               }
```

Then you are checking and updatig g8 only if it is NaN.

You will need to include a case if g7 is null, then just set the default value to be zero

Comment: Thanks, edited my answer. parseFloat will return NaN for both Null and empty string anyway

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Disregard answer. I did not know `input` was indeed valid.*

Looking at the [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/events), `input` is not a valid event type. Perhaps seeing an unrecognized type caused it to drop the rest?

Comment: `input` works with jQuery (as long as the browser supports it, which all modern ones do), but jQuery doesn't have a shortcut `.input()` method to bind handlers for it. Using `.on("input")` is fine.

Comment: Noted. I did not know that was a valid event type. Thank you.